# How to solve issue :"faraday_middleware 0.9.0 conflict with faraday (<0.9 , >= 0.7)" caused by running fastlane

Tags: osx-elcapitan, faraday, fastlane

After updating to El Captian system, my fastlane don't work well. When I update fastlane to latest version , running the command "fastlane" , it will print this error:"faraday_middleware 0.9.0 conflict with faraday (<0.9 , >= 0.7)".

Answer (score 0):

after updating to latest fastlane(1.32.4), just run more command : "sudo gem update" to update the older gems in your system . Then it is automatic solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run `[sudo] gem cleanup` to get rid of old, unused gems.